# Removing non-numeric values from data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a large matrix of data I want to import. Annoyingly all of the "NA" values are displayed as "*****" and when I read my data into R it imports as a matrix of factors.

```
str(x)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ 1: Factor w/ 704 levels "*****","0","100.1",..: 2 457 531 550 598
 $ 2: Factor w/ 689 levels "*****","0","100",..: 473 2 113 440 515
 $ 3: Factor w/ 711 levels "*****","0","100.1",..: 485 379 2 184 514
 $ 4: Factor w/ 709 levels "*****","0","100.1",..: 534 491 47 2 542
 $ 5: Factor w/ 681 levels "*****","0","100.6",..: 590 561 548 554 2


> x[988:993,988:993]
      988   989   990   991   992   993
988     0 ***** ***** ***** ***** *****
989 *****     0 ***** ***** ***** *****
990 ***** *****     0 ***** ***** *****
991 ***** ***** *****     0 ***** *****
992 ***** ***** ***** *****     0 *****
993 ***** ***** ***** ***** *****     0
```

The last few values of the matrix have no data and are displayed as "*****". I need a way of setting their values to "0" so that my matrix reads as numeric.

Comment: You could use `na.strings` attribute from `read.table` function when importing data.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add two arguments when reading the file:

`na.strings = "*****", stringsAsFactors = FALSE`